# how to get additional response in ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

I am using ajax to  showing the error message ...I am getting the values in success: function(msgqq)
This is my ajax  if want to get another response then how to get
ex:
I want

```
success: function(msgqq)
```

and

```
success: function(msg)
```

This is my ajax

```
function UserNameAvailablity(inp)
{

$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "<?=base_url()?>/system/application/views/ssitAjax.php",
    cache: false,
   data: "txtUserName="+inp,
   success: function(msgqq){
    document.getElementById('showErrmessage').innerHTML=msgqq;
      $("#showErrmessage").html(msgqq);
       if(txtUserName.value =="")
       {
         document.getElementById('txtUserName').focus();
         document.getElementById('txtUserName').value="";
       }

   }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want another response then you will have to perform an additional request.

Answer (score 1):

Call function with two parameters

```
function(msgqq, msg)
```

Or i think you can call complete function too

```
complete: function(msg){
```

But only problem with complete i think is it call even if response is failed.

Answer (score 1):

call the two functions from the success function.

```
success: function(){
     callBack1();
     callback2();
  }
```